# Source Any Where VSS, Error at recv(): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I am using Source anywhere for vss and while getting the update it gives me following error

> Error at recv(): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host.

[image: Kindly see the Error below in red Color]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some log files issue with Source any where . System Restart does the work. It's happens every few days and system restart does work. But I am still looking for proper solution

Comment: didn't yet, but will do. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

from your screenshot, the software is trying to retrieve the project/file tree structure. this error could happen if the internet connection between the client and the server is unstable. you may try refreshing to see whether the problem remains